# Como Crear un Mapa interactivo para website?

Tags: php, html, web, mapa

Estoy intentando crear una especie de mapa interactivo para un sitio web, por ejemplo un mapa de una ciudad donde se divida por colonias o barrios, en el que al clicar sobre alguna colonia te de cierta informacion, tengo la idea de colocar el mapa en forma de imagen y de alguna manera subreponer zonas interactivas sobre la imagen la cuestion es que no se me ocurre como hacerlo...

Si me pudieran ayudar para saber donde puedo encontrar informacion sobre algo parecido o si hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo...

Pongo este link de una pagina donde tiene un mapa que es algo parecido a lo que intento hacer..

[Ejemplo](https://www.nccommunityfoundation.org/communities)

Comment: el formato que te puede servir es [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG) son vectores, las formas o áreas se pueden agrupar y animar o interactivar con javascript y css

Answer (score 1):

En HTML tienes las etiquetas `<map>` y `<area>`, las cuales te permiten mediante coordenadas en una imagen, crear distinas zonas clicables. Estas zonas demás pueden tener forma de círculo, rectangulo / cuadrado o puedes definir todos los puntos y crear una zona poligonal con la forma que quieras.

Aquí te dejo la documentación en la que explica el funcionamiento y además tiene ejemplos muy claros.

[HTML Image Maps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)

[HTML map tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A como mandaste el ejemplo, creo que si debes hacerlo con varias imágenes, o incluso si no mal recuerdo lo puedes hacer con vectores de CSS o SCSS u algún tipo de hoja de estilos (seria mucho trabajo a mi parecer), pero si he usado el siguiente modulo para crear mapas interactivos [Angular Maps](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/), en este modulo para Angular puedes desplegar diferentes marcadores con descripciones, acciones y un buen de cosas que dice en la misma documentación. Lo único malo es que necesitas comprar el uso de una api key de [Google Maps Api Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=es) para que funcione bien el modulo.